# Thm: If n is an odd pseudo prime number, then $M_n = 2^n-1$ is a larger one.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

"If n is an odd pseudo prime number, then $M_n = 2^n-1$ is a larger one."

The proof in the book goes as:

Because n is a composite number, we can write $ n = rs$, with $ 1 < r \leq  s < n$. Then $ 2^r -1 \mid 2^n-1 $, or equivalently $2^r - 1 \mid  M_n $ making $M_n $ composite. By hypothesis, $2^n \equiv 2 $(mod  n)  ; hence $2^n-2 = kn $ for some integer k. It follows that

$ 2^ {M_n-1} $ = $2^{2^n-2}$ = $2^{kn} $

This yields

$ 2^ {M_n-1} - 1 $  = $2^{kn} - 1 $

= $( 2^ {n}-1)$ ($ 2^ {n(k-1)} $ + $ 2^ {n(k-2)} $ + ... + $ 2^ {n} $ + 1 )

=  $M_n$ ($ 2^ {n(k-1)} $ + $ 2^ {n(k-2)} $ + ... + $ 2^ {n} $ + 1 )

$\equiv 0$ ( mod $M_n$)

We see immediately that $2^{M_n} - 2 \equiv 0 (mod M_n) $, in light of which $M_n$ is pseudoprime.
//
//

My question is when does the assumption , n is an "odd"(in particular) pseudoprime being used. I cant see it clearly.

Comment: Apparently, the parity of $n$ was not used. (but you have a typo as "$=2^{n-1}(\ldots$ should read "$=(2^n-1)(\ldots$")

Comment: So you mean that this would also work for even pseudo primes? Are you saying that the assumption alone being pseudo prime is sufficient enough( even though its not odd?)

Comment: First of all, the book should have clarified that "pseudoprime" means "pseudoprime to base $2$". It would be interesting to find out for which numbers $n$ the number $2^n-1$ is a poulet-number (these numbers are the pseudoprimes with respect to base $2$)

Comment: @beginner I am not sure whether my answer is helpful since I did not consider even pseudoprimes. Please tell me, whether I should delete it or not.

Answer (score 1):

For which odd integers $n\ge 3$ is $$2^n-1$$ a poulet-number (pseudoprime with respect to base $2$) ?

The condition is that $$2^{2^n-2}\equiv 1\mod (2^n-1)$$ holds and $$2^n-1$$ is composite.

Let $k$ be the order of $2$ modulo $2^n-1$, in other words the smallest positive integer such that $2^k\equiv 1\mod n$. Clearly, we have $k=n$

We can conclude that $n$ must be a divisor of $2^n-2$ , so $n$ must either be prime or a poulet-number. Conversely, if $n$ is a poulet-number, then $n$ divides $2^n-2$ , hence $2^n-1$ is again a poulet-number.

Hence , if $n$ is not prime , then $n$ is a poulet-number if and only if $2^n-1$ is a poulet-number.